# CSS file loads when not called

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a question about the loading of CSS files.
I know there is only 3 ways to add style to your elements, but technically only 1 way to add a CSS file to a HTML document.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

I have a problem here though. I have a CSS file loaded that was not listed to be loaded for that area/HTML file. Even more strange, My colleague and I have the EXACT same revision on the software, the exact same data file... everything is exact except the google chrome version. But when he loads it up, the CSS file is not loaded for him and its perfect on all other machines as-well.

If there is no command to load that file, can it get stuck in the cache and be loaded for "child" forms?

This file is used on the login screen for styling and its the only place. The main site in completely separate..... yet not

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: a browser's not going to randomly reach out and grab something unless it's told to. If a css file is getting loaded, then it's being loaded via a `<link>` or `@include` type directive somewhere.

Comment: Have you looked for `@include` calls within the linked stylesheets?

Comment: @Ennui that shouldn't be the problem otherwise his colleague would have had the same thing.

Comment: @Marc B - it does not explain why it did not do the same on a colleagues machine hey. but thanks for you "help".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you colleague has the same code as you, and it's is not loading for him then it's probably cached in the browser.  You can clear out your cache in Chrome by pressing `ctrl + shift + delete` and select empty the cache.

Comment: Damn cache holding on to all types of things hey. Worked a charm, thanks